# Salesforce Dashboard - Sales Projection

Tags: salesforce, report, dashboard

Dashboard (Gauge Chart) – Need to have number which is nothing but (Closed won Opp sum in current FY /Week Number) *52. Any idea how can we get this in SF dashboard?
We can simply get Closed won Opp sum in current FY but getting current week number and multiply by 52 is not seems to be possible in SF Dashboard. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Summary report with formula.